# Error in R h2o.predict with xgboost -> java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: r, xgboost, h2o

First of all thanks for implementing XGBoost in h2o!

Unfortunately I am unable to predict from an h2o xgboost model that's loaded from disk (which I'm sure you can appreciate is really frustrating).

I am using the latest stable release of h2o i.e. 3.10.5.2 & I am using an R client.

I have included an example below that should enable you to reproduce the issue,

Thanks in advance

```
### Start h2o
    require(h2o)
    local_h2o = h2o.init()

### Source the base data set
    data(mtcars)
    h2o_mtcars = as.h2o(x = mtcars,destination_frame = 'h2o_mtcars')   

### Fit a model to be saved
    mdl_to_save = h2o.xgboost(model_id = 'mdl_to_save',y = 1,x = 2:11,training_frame = h2o_mtcars) ##This class doesnt work
    #mdl_to_save = h2o.glm(model_id = 'mdl_to_save',y = 1,x = 2:11,training_frame = h2o_mtcars) ##This class works

### Take some reference predictions
    ref_preds = h2o.predict(object = mdl_to_save,newdata = h2o_mtcars)

### Save the model to disk
    silent = h2o.saveModel(object = mdl_to_save,path = 'INSERT_PATH',force = TRUE)

### Delete the model to make sure there cant be any strange locking issues
    h2o.rm(ids = 'mdl_to_save')

### Load it back up 
    loaded_mdl = h2o.loadModel(path = 'INSERT_PATH/mdl_to_save')

### Score the model
### The h2o.predict statement below is what causes the error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    lod_preds = h2o.predict(object = loaded_mdl,newdata = h2o_mtcars)
    all.equal(ref_preds,lod_preds)
```

Comment: This is a known issue and we have a ticket open for it here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4585  I'm hoping it's fixed soon.  FYI, all open H2O-XGBoost tickets are here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/issues/?filter=21100

Comment: Ok, positive news that you guys are already working on it. Here's to a speedy fix. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

At the time I write this (January 2018), this is still a bug for `xgboost`. See [this ticket](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4585) for more information.

In the meantime, you can download the model as a `pojo` or `mojo` file

```
h2o.download_pojo(model, path = "/media/somewhere/tmp")
```

Loading the model back isn't that easy, unfortunately, but you can pass the new data via `json` to the saved `pojo` model with the function:

```
h2o.predict_json()
```

However, the new data must be provided in `json` format.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335697/r-h2o-load-a-saved-model-from-disk-in-mojo-or-pojo-format) for more details