# R h2o load a saved model from disk in MOJO or POJO format

Tags: r, io, h2o

I'm catching up on `h2o`'s MOJO and POJO model format. I'm able to save a model in MOJO/POJO with

```
h2o.download_mojo(model, path = "/media/somewhere/tmp") # ok
h2o.download_pojo(model, path = "/media/somewhere/tmp") # ok
```

which writes an object with name like `mymodel.zip` or `mymodel.java` to the directory.

However, it's not clear to me how to read it back into the server in R. I tried,

```
saved_model2 <- h2o.loadModel("/media/somewhere/tmp/mymodel.java") # not work
saved_model3 <- h2o.loadModel("/media/somewhere/tmp/mymodel.zip") # not work
```

but got error msg like this,

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 400 Bad Request (url = http://localhost:54321/99/Models.bin/)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 [1] "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing magic number 0x1CED at stream start"  
....
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 

ERROR MESSAGE:

Missing magic number 0x1CED at stream start
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are looking to make predictions on an H2O model in R, then you have three options (which method you choose depends on your use-case):

1. You can use a [binary model](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html) instead of a MOJO (or POJO). For this method, you export the model to disk using [`h2o.saveModel()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.saveModel.html) and load it back into the H2O clsuter using [`h2o.loadModel()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.loadModel.html) and make predictions using `predict(model, test)`.  This method requires having an H2O cluster running.
2. If you's still prefer to export a model to [MOJO (or POJO)](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html) format, you can use the [`h2o.mojo_predict_df()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.mojo_predict_df.html) or [`h2o.mojo_predict_csv()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.mojo_predict_csv.html) function in R to generate predictions on a test set (from an R data.frame or in a CSV file).
3. As an alternative to #2, if your data is in JSON format, you can use [`h2o.predict_json()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.predict_json.html), but it will only score one row at a time.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail on the (dis)advantages of each method? I've been using the binary model, save/load back work just fine. But as part of a production pipeline which I'd run daily, which approach is better? Thanks for the response. Quite helpful.

Comment: If the binary method is working fine for you, then you could stick with that method.  The disadvantage is that you have to always be running an H2O cluster and that the binary models are tied to specific versions of H2O.  The `h2o.predict_json()` method is more of a convenience wrapper for the standard pure Java MOJO/POJO method.  In that case, you don't need to be running an H2O cluster and you can compile the models into your bigger Java project.

Comment: The speed is faster for MOJO/POJO because you don't have to convert your test frame (usually a 1-row data.frame) into an H2OFrame before you can make predictions; you can pass the values directly as JSON.  Unless you are dealing with sub-millisecond speeds (and that speed-up matters to you), then there's no need to switch over to MOJO/POJO if you are already happy with binary models.

Answer (score 3):

`h2o.loadModel` is meant to be used with `h2o.saveModel`. If you want to compile and run a MOJO you need to do the following:

first let's say you created a MOJO from a GBM:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init(nthreads=-1)
path = "http://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/prostate/prostate.csv"
h2o_df = h2o.importFile(path)
h2o_df$RACE = as.factor(h2o_df$RACE)
model = h2o.gbm(y="CAPSULE",
        x=c("AGE", "RACE", "PSA", "GLEASON"),
        training_frame=h2o_df,
        distribution="bernoulli",
        ntrees=100,
        max_depth=4,
        learn_rate=0.1)
```

and then downloaded the MOJO and the resulting h2o-genmodel.jar file to a new experiment folder. Note that the h2o-genmodel.jar file is a library that supports scoring and contains the required readers and interpreters. This file is required when MOJO models are deployed to production.

```
modelfile = model.download_mojo(path="~/experiment/", get_genmodel_jar=True)
print("Model saved to " + modelfile)
Model saved to /Users/user/GBM_model_R_1475248925871_74.zip"
```

Then you would open a new terminal window and change into the experiment directory where you have have the MOJO files .zip and .jar.

```
$ cd experiment
```

Then you would create your main program in the experiment folder by creating a new file called main.java (for example, using "vim main.java"). Include the following contents. Note that this file is referencing the GBM model created above using R.

```
import java.io.*;
import hex.genmodel.easy.RowData;
import hex.genmodel.easy.EasyPredictModelWrapper;
import hex.genmodel.easy.prediction.*;
import hex.genmodel.MojoModel;

public class main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    EasyPredictModelWrapper model = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(MojoModel.load("GBM_model_R_1475248925871_74.zip"));

    RowData row = new RowData();
    row.put("AGE", "68");
    row.put("RACE", "2");
    row.put("DCAPS", "2");
    row.put("VOL", "0");
    row.put("GLEASON", "6");

    BinomialModelPrediction p = model.predictBinomial(row);
    System.out.println("Has penetrated the prostatic capsule (1=yes; 0=no): " + p.label);
    System.out.print("Class probabilities: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < p.classProbabilities.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
    System.out.print(",");
      }
      System.out.print(p.classProbabilities[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
  }
}
```

Then compile and run in terminal window 2 to get a display of predicted probabilities

```
$ javac -cp h2o-genmodel.jar -J-Xms2g -J-XX:MaxPermSize=128m main.java
$ java -cp .:h2o-genmodel.jar main
```

Comment: One more question : how about the POJO model ?

Comment: @horaceT yes, the `download_mojo` function saves a `java` file, which doesn't depend at all on `R`. To run this file, the compilation then must be done in `java`

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of H2O have the ability to import MOJOs via the python API:

```
# re-import saved MOJO
imported_model = h2o.import_mojo(path)

new_observations = h2o.import_file(path='new_observations.csv')
predictions = imported_model.predict(new_observations)
```

Caution: MOJO cannot be re-imported into python in older H2O versions, which lack the `h2o.import_mojo()` function.

So `h2o.save_model()` seems to have lost its role - we can use just `my_model.save_mojo()` (notice it's not a `h2o` method, but a property of the model object), as these files can be used not just for Java apps deployment, but also in python as well (in fact they still use a python-Java bridge for that internally).